# Как в битриксе убрать навигационную цепочку("хлебные крошки") с конкретной страницы?

Tags: битрикс

Есть общая навигационная цепочка на весь сайт прописанная в *header.php*. Но, на конкретной странице необходимо убрать общую навигационную цепочку и вывести отдельную. Отдельную цепочку на странице вывожу добавлением компонента `bitrix:breadcrumb`, но при этом общая цепочка прописанная в шаблоне также остаётся.
Если на страницу добавить:

```
$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("NOT_SHOW_NAV_CHAIN", "Y");
```

, то убираются все цепочки включая отдельно добавленную.

Как с этой страницы убрать только общую навигационную цепочку прописанную в шаблоне?

Answer (score 0):

Я обычно делаю так, если мне надо вывести "хлебные крошки" везде кроме главной страницы, то я просто пишу условие

```
 <? if ($GLOBALS["APPLICATION"]->GetCurPage() != "/"): ?>
                <section class="breadcrumb"> 
                <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
               "bitrix:breadcrumb",
               "breadcrumb",
                  array(
                 "PATH" => "",
                 "SITE_ID" => "s1",
                 "START_FROM" => "2",
                 "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => "breadcrumb"
            ),
            false
            );?> 
            </section>
       <? endif; ?>
```